# Can I still have a damage bonus in this type of attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage

Again, haven't played in years. So one of my weapons (a greatsword) does 2d6 piercing 1d6 force damage wise. So for most cases I'd roll 3d6. Can I still have a damage bonus like +6 just like a regular weapon?

Comment: What is the weapon?

Comment: Where is the +6 coming from?

Comment: What weapon is this? What are your character's STR, DEX and level?

Comment: Greatsword, +6 was just an example.

Comment: @Klieg I mean what magical item is the weapon? An ordinary greatsword doesn't do the 1d6 force damage.

Comment: What makes you think you _don't_ get the damage bonus? Also, your "example" is confusing. Stats don't usually get up to +6 bonus, so one would assume you either (1) got the damage bonus wrong, or (2) are confusing damage bonus with attack bonus. I suggest using +3 as an example, instead.

Comment: I'd recoomend [downloading and reading](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd) the whole SRD before progressing further. It is totally free.

Comment: I would recommend editing the question to be a bit more specific on what you are asking. Are you asking about bonuses to attack rolls, to damage rolls, to both? Are you asking about bonuses as in ability modifiers, +magic weapons, proficiency bonus? You are new, so there is no need to fret, simply reword your question a bit better so that the community can assist you better.

Comment: I thought greatswords did slashing. (PHB 149)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the weapon is wielded by you, and the relevant ability modifier for damage (Strength or Dexterity) is a bonus, yes.

PHB, page 196 / [SRD 5.1](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf) pg.96:

> When attacking with a **weapon**, you add your ability modifier - the same modifier used for the attack roll to the damage.

The relevant ability score is in PHB pg.194 / SRD 5.1 pg.94:

> Abilìty Modìfriers: The ability modifier used for a melee weapon attack is Strength, and the ability modifier used for a ranged weapon attack is Dexterity. Weapons that have the finesse or thrown property break this rule.

Comment: It's a consequence of answering an unclear question - while your answer *could* be right, it could just as easily be wrong.

Comment: Again, just getting back into it. I can make my questions a bit clearer in the future.

Comment: We cannot assume that, since it is not linked. It's better to have no answers right now than to have to scramble to edit/delete/flag/downvote when the OP finally clarifies himself. I think it's site-wide preference to have no mess to clean up when we know there are fundamental problems with the question. We're not in a hurry here :)

Comment: @Mindwin Consider, as an example, if it turns out that the OP's weapon is a special magical weapon that explicitly doesn't add damage from Str/Dex. In that case, your answer would be wrong. However, because you answered before the question was clarified, the OP might see your answer, go "Great!", and never clarify the question, so neither you nor they would ever know they'd gotten the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

### You would apply damage and attack roll modifiers the same across all weapons.

If you possess a weapon that does multiple types of damage, you treat the weapon as the base weapon it is; Flametongue Greatsword is still a greatsword. If you are proficient in greatswords, you would add your proficiency bonus to the greatsword attack roll, but not the damage roll. For damage rolls, you roll all of the damage die; 2d6 slashing for the greatsword, plus the 2d6 fire damage a Flametongue weapon adds to the attack.

You will then add the required stat modifier to the damage roll, meaning that any weapon lacking the finesse or ranged property will utilize your Strength Modifier, and any ranged or finesse weapon will utilize your Dexterity Modifier.

This means that you will add a +X to any attack you make that uses the called for ability modifier. If I had 20 Str and used my Flametongue Greatsword, I would roll for 2d6 damage, 2d6 fire damage, and then I would add a +5 to the end result damage because of my Str Modifier.

> **Damage Rolls** (PHB Pg. 196)
>
> You roll the damage die or dice, add any modifiers, and apply the
>   damage to your target. Magic weapons, special abilities, and other
>   factors can grant a bonus to damage. When attacking with a weapon, you
>   add your ability modifier—the same modifier used for the attack roll—
>   to the damage.

If you are referring to ***+magic weapons***, such as an enhanced Flametongue Greatsword, then YES, the bonus may still apply. If you find a +3 Flametongue Greatsword, then you would add a plus 3 to all attack rolls and damage rolls.